# USB Mouse Unstable and Flickering

Tags: windows, usb, mouse

I have this Microsoft USB mouse which is unstable with pointer and is flickering a lot. For example, when I open Firefox or other browser or any other text editor, the vertical scrollbar on the right hand side goes from bottom to top and forces it to stay on top. Same happens with any other app which has vertical scrollbar and due to this unstability mouse pointer forces me to stay at the top. Mouse pointer also moves randomly without touching it. I checked to see if it's due to some process and removed svchost.exe which was taking more load, removing it from task manager temporarily resolves issue but it keeps on persisting.

Is it issue of USB port or mouse has reached it's end of life cycle ?

Comment: Sounds like dust got in your mouse's optical receiver.

Comment: I am curious as to what service should be affecting it. Assuming you are running Vista or later, if you right-click the relevant svchost.exe instance in the Task Manager and click *Go To Service(s)* then which service is highlighted? For how long does this resolve the issue? In the mean time, do you have any special drivers installed? Have you tried a different USB port? Have you checked for viruses? If you know your way around with the keyboard then you could try uninstalling/reinstalling the mouse in the Device Manager.

Comment: @digitxp : It sounds as though he is having issues with scrolling as well which would suggest it's not just the optical receiver that is faulty.

Comment: I'm using windows XP SP3. No extra drivers installed as it detected the mouse with generic MS driver. I don't have mark's process explorer, so not sure which process is affecting the mouse. No viruses. Checked on 2nd port, same issue. I'll check if reinstalling works.

Comment: If you open the Task Manager you should be able to get the PID (Process Identifier) of the relevant svchost.exe instance.  If you then type *tasklist /SVC* into a command prompt it will show you the service(s) associated with each svchost.exe instance - you can match it up using the PID.

Comment: There are six svchost.exe processes running. 1) DCOM server process launcher 2)Remote procedure call 3) Loading 20 additional processes 4) and 5) Generic host processes. 6) Windows Image acquisition process. Checked and matched with PID. I removed DCOM and WIA based process as i mentioned earlier. These two taking more load and are always at the top of task manager.

Comment: I have been assuming that it's a desktop that you are using and not a laptop. Is this correct?

Comment: How long has this been happening? Does it still happen if you disconnect from your network? It seems vaguely plausible that someone could be playing a prank by controlling it remotely. Otherwise I think your mouse is probably faulty and you should either borrow another mouse or test your mouse on someone else's computer.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that it is worth starting in safe mode to see if it still happens as it should help to eliminate software as the cause.

Comment: Yes, using desktop(old assembled machine- 2006 motherboard, mouse and keyboard). It is so difficult to use this desktop. I can't even type properly. This is happening for last six months or so. But more annoying for last two months. It happens even without network connection (i use USB dongle to connect) and there are no means to connect to the internet, no wired or wi-fi network here. I've not tried safe mode. But as you said, it could be either USB ports dieing on me or have to change the mouse.

Comment: If you are also getting keyboard issues and they stared at the same time then I suspect there could be a problem with the motherboard itself or the drivers relating to it. Perhaps its worth trying an Ubuntu live CD to see how it behaves. If it works perfectly then I would suggest a full reinstall of Windows, including the latest drivers. If on the other hand you get similar problems then you know that there is something wrong with the hardware.

Comment: @James, I installed new driver and also replaced old mouse with temporary one, it seemed to be working for now but with still some flickering. I guess it's upto USB ports now.I can't comment further as this form is asking me to extend this discussion to chat instead. So i'm going to close the question. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the system was with the faulty mouse. The old mouse had issues related to the tracking and now changing the mouse with new USB mouse resolves the issue.